# How to integrate flutter module to existing native android app?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I wanted to integrate flutter package into my native android app by following tutorials on flutter website,but I keep getting following errors.
Could not find com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_debug:1.0.
This is my app build.gradle file

```
 dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'io.flutter:flutter:2.8.0'

    implementation project(':flutter')

    debugImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_debug:1.0'
    profileImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_profile:1.0'
    releaseImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_release:1.0'

    releaseImplementation('com.example.my_flutter:flutter_release:1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

}
```

settings.gradle file

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

dependencyResolutionManagement {

    String storageUrl = System.env.FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL ?: "https://storage.googleapis.com"

    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven {
            url 'D:\\AndroidStudioProjects\\NativeAndroid\\flutterModule\\build\\host\\outputs\\repo'
        }
        maven {
            url "$storageUrl/download.flutter.io"
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Native Android"
include ':app'

setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))
evaluate(new File(
        settingsDir.parentFile,
        'flutterModule/.android/include_flutter.groovy'
))
```

This is my error:

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that error by changing

```
debugImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_debug:1.0'
profileImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_profile:1.0'
releaseImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_release:1.0'
```

to then sync

```
debugImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_release:1.0:debug@aar'
profileImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_release:1.0:profile@aar'
releaseImplementation 'com.example.fluttermodule:flutter_release:1.0:release@aar'
```

Also change your settings.gradle file

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

to

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)
```

or you can just delete whole dependencyResolutionManagement.

then add to your app build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```